# Como abrir um pop-up

Tags: php, popup

Quero colocar um link com o nome e que abra um página tipo *pop up*.

```
<p>';
if($exibe['Nome1'] != NULL) {
echo '<p><b>Nome: </b>'.$exibe["Nome1"].'';
}'</p>
```

Quero  mostrar o `Nome` e sobre ele um link para abrir o *pop up*.

Answer (score 4):

Oi, em php acho que não é possível, mas você pode usar javasript, segue o código:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.suapagina.com', 'Titulo da Janela', 'STATUS=NO, TOOLBAR=NO, LOCATION=NO, DIRECTORIES=NO, RESISABLE=NO, SCROLLBARS=YES, TOP=10, LEFT=10, WIDTH=770, HEIGHT=400');">Clique para abrir a janela POP-up</a>
```

Você também pode usar esse site para gerar o código: 
http://blogomaniag6.blogspot.com.br/

Espero que seja isso! Abraço!

Answer (score 4):

Tente usar assim então:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function abrir(URL) {

  var width = 150;
  var height = 250;

  var left = 99;
  var top = 99;

  window.open(URL,'janela', 'width='+width+', height='+height+', top='+top+', left='+left+', scrollbars=yes, status=no, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, fullscreen=no');

}
</script>



<?php
echo '<p><a href="abrir("http://www.meusite.com.br");">'.$exibe["Nome1"].'</a></p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não vai conseguir com php puro. Para abrir o popup, vai ter que colocar um trecho de código javascript. Algo como:

```
<p>
    <a href="window.open('http://google.com.br', 'new-window');"><?php echo $exibe["Nome1"]; ?></a>
</p>
```