# Como abrir um pop-up sem usar JavaScript?

Tags: html, popup

Como abrir um pop-up sem usar o onclick ou qualquer outra função JavaScript?

Comment: Só uma pergunta, por que não usar JavaScript? acho que o que o @bfavaretto falou, você talvez queira um "modal" (na verdade um div sobreposto os demais elementos), mas mesmo assim este "modal" pode usar JavaScript (ou o pseudo `:target` como na resposta do @Zuul)

Comment: Encontras-te solução para esta resposta? Alguma das respostas ajudou?

Answer (score 27):

Podes utilizar CSS3 para criar uma *popup*, abrir e fechar a mesma sem recorrer a JavaScript.

O truque está no uso da *pseudo class* [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) que nos permite alterar declarações para o elemento `.modalDialog` e assim apresentar o mesmo.

**Exemplo**

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Popup</h2>
    <p>Isto é uma popup toda bonitinha a funcionar apenas com CSS3.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>Exemplo em detalhe em (c) [Webdesigner Depot](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/).</sup>

Comment: Muito bom, realmente o `:target` foi muito bem empregado no exemplo, obrigado pela contribuição. O +1 já estava garantido :)

Comment: Cheguei atrasado, mas sensacional!

Answer (score 8):

Este método não usa Javascript nem CSS3. Funciona basicamente assim:
A página fica dentro de um container e a popup fica escondida numa parte overflow do container. Quando você clica na âncora, o usuário é levado para essa parte do container.

```css
#container, #popup{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#pag{
    width: 600px;
    height: 1200px;
}
#popup{
    margin-top: 600px;
    background-color: grey
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="pag">
        <a href="#popup">Abrir popup</a><p>
        Conteúdo da pagina
        <div id="popup">
            <a href="#pag">fechar popup</a><p>
            Conteúdo da POPUP
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Bastante criativo, adicionei o StackSnippet para os demais testarem o seu exemplo

Answer (score 5):

O melhor que dá pra fazer é forçar a abertura em outra aba (ou janela, quem decide é o navegador):

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Comment: oi amigo, Eu gostaria de fazer igual o Facebook,Twitter etc.

Comment: @XiroNakamura Facebook, Twitter etc usam JavaScript! E muito dele...

Comment: @XiroNakamura Talvez seja um diálogo modal, e não um pop-up o que você está querendo. Como isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51718/caixa-de-aviso-ap%C3%B3s-clique-em-div

Comment: Conforme a pergunta descreve, realmente é a resposta correta rs +1

Comment: Amigos eu acho que é um pop up mesmo. Eu quero clicar no botão e abrir uma janela com uma pagina do site. tipo o Twitter (https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons) pode ser em JavaScript mas desde que o link possa ficar igual o do Twitter.

Comment: Então @XiroNakamura, como o do Twitter é o que explicam naquela outra pergunta que apontei como duplicata da sua pergunta anterior: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21240/como-abrir-um-pop-up

Comment: opa amigo, mas eu queria sem o window.open. lá no Twitter ele(link) esta totalmente "limpo" sem essas funções.<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="">Tweet</a>

Comment: @XiroNakamura O botão do twitter certamente inclui algum JS para fazer isso, não dá pra abrir esse tipo de janela sem `window.open`. Só que o `window.open` não precisa estar dentro da tag `<a>`, o JS deve estar separado.

Comment: @XiroNakamura `<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>` O código com window.open deve estar nesse `//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js`

Comment: É MUITO código kkkkkk... mas não achei o window.open.

Comment: @XiroNakamura se você olha mais atentamente notará um `d.createElement` e a url `://platform.twi‌​tter.com/widgets.js` ou seja, este url contem o resto do javascript e se você abrir no navegador e usar Ctrl+F e pesquisar a palavra `window.open` provavelmente irá encontra-lá.

Answer (score -2):

consegui fazer \o/... o que vcs acham do código? dá para melhorar? E se o js estiver desativado no navegador do cliente, teria alguma maneira dele executar o código?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>  

<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#enviar").click(function( e ){
e.preventDefault();

var width = 550;
var height = 550;

var left = 99;
var top = 99;

window.open(enviar,'janela', 'width='+width+', height='+height+',top='+top+'left='+left+', scrollbars=yes, status=no, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, fullscreen=no');

 });
 });
</script>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" id="enviar" data-text="https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl">Tweet</a>
```

Comment: O titulo diz sem JavaScript, portanto as resposta para mim a resposta é meio sem lógica, sem querer ser chato, mas ao meu ver as outras resposta estão corretas e a sua a única errada. Espero que não se chateie, somos uma comunidade de perguntas e respostas e não uma comunidade de suporte e discussões, seja bem vindo :)

Comment: Oi Guilherme, o problema é que não fui muito claro na pergunta.E quando o adm fez a edição a mesma não condizia com a minha realidade. Mas consegui resolver o problema e quero apenas respostas para dúvidas técnicas que citei acima.

Comment: Boa tarde, não foi um adm que editou, somos uma comunidade qualquer um pode editar, desde que seja aprovado por usuário com maior experiencia, aqui não somos um fórum de debates, mas sim um *Q&A*, para ser mais objetivo, somos uma comunidade de perguntas e respostas, se a resposta não condiz com a pergunta, tecnicamente não é uma resposta. Se a pergunta fosse algo assim: Como o tweeter usar pop-ups sem javascript? talvez a resposta fosse válida (apesar que seria uma pergunta bem ruim, portanto a pergunta fala:...

Comment: ...*Como abrir um pop-up sem usar o onclick ou qualquer outra função JavaScript?* e a resposta tem que ser conforme a pergunta, claro que ela pode conter mais detalhes. Em outras palavras, a sua pergunta não é só para ti, mas para toda comunidade, tente fazer ela ser útil a outros, pois se não será uma pergunta mais solicitando suporte do que uma pergunta dentro do escopo da comunidade... isto é só minha opinião e se alguém discorda, por favor pode me criticar não irei levar a mal, só estou tentando orientar.